# How can I apply <Common Failure Conditions> to all builds on the same server in TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, dsl, continuous-delivery

How can I apply the condition highlighted in the screenshot to all builds on the same server in TeamCity? Perhaps you can find a directory with all the DSL on Kotlin and replace some flag with false to true?

Thank you for your time and answers!

[image]

Comment: I cannot find this anywhere in TeamCity's Kotlin DSL documentation. Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: I did figure out this much - how to apply that setting using Kotlin. This might be useful in trying to create a wrapper function that applies this setting to all build configurations. Add `option("shouldFailBuildOnAnyErrorMessage", "true") ` directly in a Template or Build Type.